# SQL Server Sort Order to Binary Search on SQL Server 2008 SP1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I am installing an OLT Software that requires Windows SQL Server 2008.

I am getting this error below;

> The database sort order must be "binary sort". Please run the
>   Transact-SQL command sp_helpsort to check the current database sort
>   order.

Output of `sp_helpsort` is;

```
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive,
width-insensitive for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Page 1252 for 
non-Unicode Data
```

How could I change sort order to "binary sort" in order to proceed installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either reinstall SQL and change the collation during the installation or rebuild the system databases to change the collation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338788/how-to-change-the-master-database-collation-in-sql-server